# What is considered as a good fit using the fraction deviance?

Tags: logistic, goodness-of-fit, regularization, glmnet, deviance

I am using the fraction deviance given by Hastie et. al (2015),

$\mathcal{D}_{\lambda}^{2}=\frac{\mathcal{D}\mathrm{ev}_{\mathrm{null}}-\mathcal{D}\mathrm{ev}_{\lambda}}{\mathcal{D}\mathrm{ev}_{\mathrm{null}}}$

I am trying to understand what is considered as a good fit model and what is considered as a bad model fit? Is it like that or I have to use the $\mathcal{D}\mathrm{ev}_{\lambda}$ to check if my model has a good fit?

I think I am mixing the Deviance with the Fraction Deviance, can someone explain please?

Comment: The formula has the standard $R^2$ form: It measures the reduction in some measure of disagreement between outcome and prediction that the model achieves relative to the best intercept-only model. It's just not possible to say what a "good fit" is without context. Most important context: What are you estimating the model for? What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: @CloseToC - I am using glmnet where I have fitted the lasso with logistic regression. `glmnet` finds $\lambda$ which doesnt change the deviance. so i am trying to understand if that is the best model

Comment: If you used cv.glmnet to select $\lambda$ it was chosen, per default, to minimise $\mathcal{D}\mathrm{ev}_{\lambda}$ which means it has the largest log likelihood (in the data sets not used for training). So it that sense it's the best model. The fraction deviance tells you how good the model predicts compared to the best intercept model. A low value there doesn't mean something went wrong with the crossvalidation procedure that found $\lambda$